# How does linux kernel lockdep record lock-class dependency?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, locking, linux-device-driver, deadlock

I got a warning as below which is a AB-BA deadlock issue. But I don't understand how the 'existing dependency' happened.

It looks like: kvm_read_guest() held (&mm->mmap_sem), then reading userspace memory (which is not ready yet) caused page_fault() invoked, then in i915_gem_fault() it tries to hold lock class (&dev->struct_mutex) which only has one instance.

**But this sequence must haven't happened.** Otherwise, double-lock already happed, since intel_vgpu_create_workload() has held (&dev->struct_mutex) already:

> (&dev->struct_mutex)->(&mm->mmap_sem)->(&dev->struct_mutex)

**So how could lockdep find such 'existing dependency'?**

Another question is '#0 (&mm->mmap_sem)' is held by __might_fault()->might_lock_read(). But might_lock_read() only temporarily accquire the lock. Then why there is a lock sequence "(&mm->mmap_sem)->(&dev->struct_mutex)"?

```
[  113.934800] ======================================================
[  113.940963] WARNING: possible circular locking dependency detected
[  113.947131] 4.16.0-rc5+ #44 Tainted: G     U
[  113.952257] ------------------------------------------------------
[  113.958424] qemu-system-x86/4298 is trying to acquire lock:
[  113.963983]  (&mm->mmap_sem){++++}, at: [<0000000052776050>] __might_fault+0x36/0x80
[  113.971716]
               but task is already holding lock:
[  113.977542]  (&dev->struct_mutex){+.+.}, at: [<000000002a25c66b>] intel_vgpu_create_workload+0x3d1/0x550 [i915]
[  113.987643]
               which lock already depends on the new lock.

[  113.995801]
               the existing dependency chain (in reverse order) is:
[  114.003268]
               -> #1 (&dev->struct_mutex){+.+.}:
[  114.009113]        i915_mutex_lock_interruptible+0x66/0x170 [i915]
[  114.015301]        i915_gem_fault+0x1d0/0x620 [i915]
[  114.020273]        __do_fault+0x19/0xed
[  114.024108]        __handle_mm_fault+0x9fa/0x1140
[  114.028806]        handle_mm_fault+0x1a7/0x390
[  114.033240]        __do_page_fault+0x286/0x530
[  114.037677]        page_fault+0x45/0x50
[  114.041503]
               -> #0 (&mm->mmap_sem){++++}:
[  114.046901]        __might_fault+0x60/0x80
[  114.051008]        __kvm_read_guest_page+0x3d/0x80 [kvm]
[  114.056319]        kvm_read_guest+0x47/0x80 [kvm]
[  114.061024]        kvmgt_rw_gpa+0x9d/0x110 [kvmgt]
[  114.065833]        copy_gma_to_hva+0x71/0x100 [i915]
[  114.070818]        intel_gvt_scan_and_shadow_ringbuffer+0xc4/0x210 [i915]
[  114.077617]        intel_gvt_scan_and_shadow_workload+0xc7/0x480 [i915]
[  114.084240]        intel_vgpu_create_workload+0x3d9/0x550 [i915]
[  114.090258]        intel_vgpu_submit_execlist+0xc0/0x2a0 [i915]
[  114.096190]        elsp_mmio_write+0xcb/0x140 [i915]
[  114.101170]        intel_vgpu_mmio_reg_rw+0x250/0x4f0 [i915]
[  114.106845]        intel_vgpu_emulate_mmio_write+0xaa/0x240 [i915]
[  114.113014]        intel_vgpu_rw+0x200/0x250 [kvmgt]
[  114.117972]        intel_vgpu_write+0x164/0x1f0 [kvmgt]
[  114.123188]        __vfs_write+0x33/0x170
[  114.127192]        vfs_write+0xc5/0x1c0
[  114.131022]        SyS_pwrite64+0x90/0xb0
[  114.135025]        do_syscall_64+0x70/0x1c0
[  114.139203]        entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x42/0xb7
[  114.144765]
               other info that might help us debug this:

[  114.152754]  Possible unsafe locking scenario:

[  114.158664]        CPU0                    CPU1
[  114.163185]        ----                    ----
[  114.167714]   lock(&dev->struct_mutex);
[  114.171541]                                lock(&mm->mmap_sem);
[  114.177449]                                lock(&dev->struct_mutex);
[  114.183790]   lock(&mm->mmap_sem);
[  114.187186]
                *** DEADLOCK ***

[  114.193095] 3 locks held by qemu-system-x86/4298:
[  114.197789]  #0:  (&gvt->lock){+.+.}, at: [<0000000087b40252>] intel_vgpu_emulate_mmio_write+0x64/0x240 [i915]
[  114.207792]  #1:  (&dev->struct_mutex){+.+.}, at: [<000000002a25c66b>] intel_vgpu_create_workload+0x3d1/0x550 [i915]
[  114.218314]  #2:  (&kvm->srcu){....}, at: [<00000000e49701e8>] kvmgt_rw_gpa+0x4c/0x110 [kvmgt]
[  114.226913]
               stack backtrace:
[  114.231263] CPU: 0 PID: 4298 Comm: qemu-system-x86 Tainted: G     U           4.16.0-rc5+ #44
[  114.239771] Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 7040/0Y7WYT, BIOS 1.2.8 01/26/2016
[  114.247155] Call Trace:
[  114.249600]  dump_stack+0x7c/0xbe
[  114.252909]  print_circular_bug.isra.33+0x21b/0x228
[  114.257781]  __lock_acquire+0xf7d/0x1470
[  114.261698]  ? lock_acquire+0xec/0x1e0
[  114.265440]  lock_acquire+0xec/0x1e0
[  114.269008]  ? __might_fault+0x36/0x80
[  114.272749]  __might_fault+0x60/0x80
[  114.276317]  ? __might_fault+0x36/0x80
[  114.280066]  __kvm_read_guest_page+0x3d/0x80 [kvm]
[  114.284856]  kvm_read_guest+0x47/0x80 [kvm]
[  114.289042]  kvmgt_rw_gpa+0x9d/0x110 [kvmgt]
[  114.293333]  copy_gma_to_hva+0x71/0x100 [i915]
[  114.297797]  intel_gvt_scan_and_shadow_ringbuffer+0xc4/0x210 [i915]
[  114.304091]  intel_gvt_scan_and_shadow_workload+0xc7/0x480 [i915]
[  114.310206]  intel_vgpu_create_workload+0x3d9/0x550 [i915]
[  114.315709]  intel_vgpu_submit_execlist+0xc0/0x2a0 [i915]
[  114.321140]  elsp_mmio_write+0xcb/0x140 [i915]
[  114.325596]  intel_vgpu_mmio_reg_rw+0x250/0x4f0 [i915]
[  114.330746]  intel_vgpu_emulate_mmio_write+0xaa/0x240 [i915]
[  114.336396]  intel_vgpu_rw+0x200/0x250 [kvmgt]
[  114.340833]  intel_vgpu_write+0x164/0x1f0 [kvmgt]
[  114.345533]  __vfs_write+0x33/0x170
[  114.349016]  ? common_file_perm+0x68/0x250
[  114.353104]  ? security_file_permission+0x36/0xb0
[  114.357803]  vfs_write+0xc5/0x1c0
[  114.361113]  SyS_pwrite64+0x90/0xb0
[  114.364597]  ? trace_hardirqs_off_thunk+0x1a/0x1c
[  114.369293]  do_syscall_64+0x70/0x1c0
[  114.372950]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x42/0xb7
[  114.377994] RIP: 0033:0x7f0ca8a29da3
[  114.381562] RSP: 002b:00007f0c98dc96c0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000012
[  114.389121] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f0ca8a29da3
[  114.396240] RDX: 0000000000000004 RSI: 00007f0c98dc96f0 RDI: 0000000000000019
[  114.403362] RBP: 00007f0c98dc9710 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00000000ffffffff
[  114.410484] R10: 0000000000002230 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000000
[  114.417605] R13: 00007ffdd628d02f R14: 00007f0c98dca9c0 R15: 0000000000000000
```

in function intel_vgpu_create_workload:

```
    mutex_lock(&dev_priv->drm.struct_mutex);
    ret = intel_gvt_scan_and_shadow_workload(workload);
    mutex_unlock(&dev_priv->drm.struct_mutex);
```

Comment: You correctly noted in the title, that lockdep operates not on a single locks, but on **lock classes**. That is you may have "A1,B2" and "A3,B4" lock sequences, which don't cause a deadlock, but are detected by lockdep as a circular dependency. So, what do you want from use? Confirmation that "A1,B2" is actually happens? Or the same about "A3,B4"? Or confirmation that your code is actually safe (or unsafe) while lockdep issues the warning?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to make sure that whether this is a valid ‘false report’. In this report, I’m sure there is only one instance of lock class (&dev->struct_mutex) . So I think sequence "A1,B2" and "A1,B4" is not possible,right?